# How to paste in place in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get vim to paste in place without breaking everything : )

I've got ctrl + p working to where it pastes something beginning in the slot the cursor is covering. This works great because when pasting multiple lines, they're aligned. No extra single space for the first line, yay! I'd like to achieve the same thing for normal p, which usually begins pasting in the slot after where the cursor is.

Any help would rock!

By the way here are my mappings for the ctrl + p and ctrl + y

```
nnoremap <C-y> "+y
vnoremap <C-y> "+y
nnoremap <C-p> "+gP
vnoremap <C-p> "+gP
```

I essentially want the same behavior for p as I have with ctrl + p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `P` as opposed to `p`.

If you really want the exact same behavior with `p` as you have with `ctrl-p` you can remap it.

```
nnoremap p "+gP
vnoremap p "+gP
```

Comment: No, I don't mean pasting from the system clipboard, but thanks! `nnoremap p P` worked great!

Comment: @Costa think twice if you really want to have that mapping. E.g. you yanked two lines, with different `p and P`, you can choose to paste the two lines below or above the current line. You disabled `p`, you lose the option.

Comment: Maybe remap `p` to `P` and `P` to `p` so that you don't lose the option but the default (`p`) is the key that you want most of the time.

Comment: @Zach ok...anyone has his own preference. what good is, vim allows you to customize as you will. =)

Comment: Yes, its one of the things that really brings vim apart from other editors. If you decide vim doesn't have a feature that you would like, you can just add it yourself.

Comment: @Zach I would say Vim is weak in that area compared to Emacs.